# Excel find repeated value based on another condition

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following columns in Excel with values but column C's value is changing, I need to find the row with values based on column c
Register Number, Name, Status

```
A       B               C     
XAX2    ABCABCABC   Rejected
XAX3    YYY         Rejected
XAX2    ABCABCABC   Rejected
XAX5    YYY         Rejected
XAX2    ABCABCABC   Approved
XAX7    YYY         Rejected
XAXW    ABCABCABC   Rejected
XAXW    ABCABCABC   Approved
```

After a search of "Rejected" need to Show only " XAX3 YYYY REJECTED", "XAX5 YYY   Rejected" & "XAX7   YYY    Rejected" only latest updated row
After a search of "Approved" need to Show only " XAX2 ABCABCABC Approved" & "XAXW   ABCABCABC   Approved" last row. How can i make  this formula in excel

Comment: Why does a search of 'Rejected' show only "XAX3 YYYY REJECTED" and not the others?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add Rejected results will be XAX3, XAX5 & XAX7 with YYY as name ......ABCABCABC (XAX2), (XAXW) got approved on 4th chance so it will not appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your requirements right, you can use a layout like this:

[image]

[image]

The formula in cell F1 is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$8,SMALL(IF($E$1="Rejected",IF(($B$1:$B$8="YYY")*($C$1:$C$8=$E$1)=1,ROW(A$1:A$8),999),IF(($B$1:$B$8<>"YYY")*($C$1:$C$8=$E$1)=1,ROW(A$1:A$8),999)),ROW())),"")
```

Which works correctly only when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and then you can drag the formula down to fill the other cells. If you change the value of E1 to Rejected or Approved, the list in column F, G and H will change accordingly.

The formula in G1 and H1 respectively are:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B$1:B$8,SMALL(IF($E$1="Rejected",IF(($B$1:$B$8="YYY")*($C$1:$C$8=$E$1)=1,ROW(A$1:A$8),999),IF(($B$1:$B$8<>"YYY")*($C$1:$C$8=$E$1)=1,ROW(A$1:A$8),999)),ROW())),"")

=IFERROR(INDEX(C$1:C$8,SMALL(IF($E$1="Rejected",IF(($B$1:$B$8="YYY")*($C$1:$C$8=$E$1)=1,ROW(A$1:A$8),999),IF(($B$1:$B$8<>"YYY")*($C$1:$C$8=$E$1)=1,ROW(A$1:A$8),999)),ROW())),"")
```

You can get the excel file I have in the screenshots [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23298677/DavidJohn.xlsx) (I will remove it in a week or so).

NOTE: If it doesn't matter what's in column B, use those:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$8,SMALL(IF($E$1="Rejected",IF($C$1:$C$8=$E$1,ROW(A$1:A$8),999),IF($C$1:$C$8=$E$1,ROW(A$1:A$8),999)),ROW())),"")

=IFERROR(INDEX(B$1:B$8,SMALL(IF($E$1="Rejected",IF($C$1:$C$8=$E$1,ROW(A$1:A$8),999),IF($C$1:$C$8=$E$1,ROW(A$1:A$8),999)),ROW())),"")

=IFERROR(INDEX(C$1:C$8,SMALL(IF($E$1="Rejected",IF($C$1:$C$8=$E$1,ROW(A$1:A$8),999),IF($C$1:$C$8=$E$1,ROW(A$1:A$8),999)),ROW())),"")
```

Comment: In the formula i can see "YYY" does this will cause any conflicts while it is in a sheet of 2300 rows..???

Comment: @DavidJohn No, just make sure that the references are adjusted. E.g. `A$1:A$8` will become `A$1:A$2800` for 2800 rows. If you have headers, you'll need further adjustment inside the formula aside from the references.

Comment: Checked and "Rejected" is showing only when its matching column B as YYY, No problem came from 2800 rows, but the results are not shows due to the above...

Comment: @DavidJohn Oh wait, you mean you need to see _all_ rejected when rejected is selected and _all_ approved when approved is selected, irrespective of what's in column B? I edited my answer to include this, and updated the excel that you can download.

Comment: Correct, I need to Get all Rejected & All approved, If XX2 (cloum A) is Rejected 2 times and approved 1 time, this will come only in approved list, i.e If Colum A number got an approval in a life time it will remain approved regardless of its past rejection...same for rejection scenario...All the base will be colum A & colum C (Colum B is only name)

Comment: Okay @DavidJohn The edited formulas should be what you're looking for then!